# Disable cache in IOS application with UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, request

I have an application IOS who load the same url but with different content every 5/10 seconds.
On my website I count how often my url websie is call by my application.
When I call my website in a browser (safari/chrome/fiefox...)
My website count the good number of times.
When I call my website with my Application. my website don't count the good number of times. it's lower.

I think that is on account of the cache.
How to desable cache on a Uiwebview IOS application ?
I have already in my code `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` with my request but I think this is when I load in my UIwebview.

```
NSString *html = @"<head></head><body style='padding:0;margin:0;'><script src='http://url_with_content.com'></SCRIPT></body>";
NSString *script = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", html];
[adView loadHTMLString:script baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Clear all Cookies and cache
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: I test but I have the same poblem !

Comment: Your only option then is to remove the webview and create a new one.  There are no public api's for clearing the history of a webview.

Comment: I remove my webview and I create a new one... Adding too a paramater `&time=timestamp` to have a different url/html code !! It's same ! I don't understand !!